# Get Byte Values as String

Tags: java, string, arrays

I have byte array "result" which contains values like

> [0, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9]

I want to convert it to String like

> 0,1,4,5,3,2,6,7,8,9.

I have taken below approached but it didn't work.

```
String str = new String(result, "ISO-8859-1"); Used "UTF-8" Character set also.
String str  =  Arrays.toString(result);
```

Comment: Why didn't it work? What was the result? How does this compare to what you wanted? Does [this](http://www.asciitable.com/) provide any clue at to what happened?

Comment: resturn result is [ , 0, ,,  , 1, ,,  , 4, ,,  , 5, ,,  , 3, ,,  , 2, ,,  , 6, ,,  , 7, ,,  , 8, ,,  , 9,  ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a great solution, but this seems to work :

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[]  result = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    String str;
    try {
        str = new String (result, "ISO-8859-1" ).trim();
        str  =  Arrays.toString(result).trim();
        str = str.replaceAll(" ","");
        System.out.println ( "str = ["+str+"]");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Produces output :

```
str = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]
```

Comment: Nope, not great at all. Why do you call `str = new String (result, "ISO-8859-1" ).trim()` followed by `str  =  Arrays.toString(result).trim()`? What do you think this achieves?

Answer (score 0):

As there are no simple way to convert `byte[]` to `List<Byte>` to use in `String.join()`, or into a stream, a code would be a bit more verbose than you'd like:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (byte b : result)
    sb.append((int) b).append(',');
String str = sb.length() == 0 ? "" : sb.substring(0, sb.length() - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

i didnt understand if you want a string or a string array but for the "a string":

```
String str = "";
for(byte a : byteArr){
  str+=(char)a;
  str+=",";
}
```

should work